# sending query strings using Javascript

Tags: javascript, php, http

suppose that I have two pages ( A and B ) , and I want to pass **insensitive** data from A to B , why I shouldn't  set a query string variables containing my data in the target page  URL(B) ,  and then retrieve my data from there using javascript (`window.location.href`) too , I mean why I should use PHP $_GET array ?

Comment: Because Page A no longer exists when you get to page B

Comment: You can also use cookies / localstorage in theory.

Comment: php is server side, javascript is on client side.. Thumb rule- be it **sensitive** or **insensitive** data, use server side implementation for retrieving and changing..!

Comment: @Sundhansu 
if I want to just pass a small amount of data without the need of storing it in the server or changing it , is it OK to use javascript isn't it ?

Comment: **It is OK for insensitive data.** The main argument against this is that you will end up with ugly URLs.

Comment: @mahmoudnezarsarhan You can definitely use js.. it's more about perception, style and taste of your programming/coding(keeping this question in context). You can pass data using js or use server side implementation, it's up to you. However why server side should be preferred is because of security reasons, javascript can be modified at run time. But as you have stated the data is insensitive, you can absolutely go ahead with using js, if you feel comfortable with it

Comment: Agree with @MonkeyZeus, you could end up with ugly, long URLs, especially if you have space(s) within a String that you are trying to pass as the data. It could look messy with (`%20`)s and stuff being added in the URL.

Comment: @SudhansuChoudhary  thank you for this  clear answer 
please put it as an answer so other people can make use of it in future ♥

Comment: Sure @mahmoudnezarsarhan I've put it as the answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Putting my comments as the answer **as suggested by OP**,

php is server side, javascript is on client side.. Thumb rule- be it **sensitive** or **insensitive** data, use server side implementation for retrieving and changing..!

You can definitely use js.. it's more about perception, style and taste of your programming/coding(keeping this question in context). You can pass data using js(URLs as you have mentioned) or use server side implementation, it's up to you. However why server side should be preferred is because of security reasons, javascript can be modified at run time. But as you have stated the data is insensitive, you can absolutely go ahead with using js, if you feel comfortable with it.

And as @MonkeyZeus has commented, you could end up with ugly, long URLs. Especially if you have space(s) within a String that you are trying to pass as the data. It could look messy with (%20)s and stuff being added in the URL.